# Remote video streaming with Pepper and NAO robots

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nao-robot, pepper

I am trying to remotely stream videos and images from the cameras of the Pepper and NAO robots to my laptop.

First, I used a while loop to repeatedly capture images from the NAO's camera and processed the images through opencv. However, as you can imagine, this only provided me with a framerate of about 1 fps.

Then I tried to access the camera through opencv's videocapture, but it is not working properly.

Next, I attempted to use gstreamer 1.0 for python on Windows, but the Windows version seems to be missing a number of elements, even though I have all of the required plugins (base, good, bad, ugly).

Also, I am trying to avoid using ROS because I am having issues using it with the python 2.7 naoqi SDK of the Pepper and NAO robots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: gstreamer with mjpeg/jpegenc or H263 is the best solution. If you want less compression, transfering QVGA in grey using naoqi is not so bad.

Comment: I've tried using the solutions below, which both use jpegenc, but the NAO's camera still isn't streaming. Is it expected to take awhile for the stream to process?

Comment: I forget to precise to must ask naoqi to release the camera to be able to use gstreamer manually. So stop naoqi (shell command "nao stop") or just stop ALVideoDevice (python or qicli api call "ALVideoDevice.exit()")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gstreamer should already be installed on the robot, so you could run it on the robot with a command like this:

> gst-launch-0.10 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video-top ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! multipartmux! tcpserversink port=3000

... and then you can open the stream from your computer, for example with vlc:

> vlc tcp://ip.of.the.robot:3000

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the errors by changing the device to /dev/video0 but it is still not showing the NAO's camera stream

Comment: UPDATE: Realized I had to run vlc to actually view the stream. Novice move on my part. It shows the stream on my computer but there is significant lag. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: When I tried the gstream all plugin like x264 and hlssink wasn't installed. Any ideas install gstream plugin on nao. On a standard distro its easy to compile the from source code. Are there any information how to compile from source code on naoqi os?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [site](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-aldebaran/LhmKTxyTn1Y) as an orientation:

It describes how to achieve camera stream at 25fps VGA wih Pepper using:

> gstreamer to create an UDP (+RTP) stream of the front (/dev/video0)
>   and bottom (/dev/video1) camera from Pepper, the stream is then
>   retrieved on the PC_HOST with gscam and remapped in
>   /pepper_robot/camera tree.

Important tip is to **disable autonomous life**!

Comment: I followed the SSH commands provided in the link, but the camera stream is not loading. It seems as if it is stuck. Do you know if it takes awhile for the stream to load?

Comment: It doesn't take long to get the stream. On nao6 it's nice when there are two cameras. The upper camera was blocked by other processes but the lower one bottom worked right away.